# Cómo hacer que espere a la respuesta de un ContentDialog en UWP y continue el programa

Tags: c#, async-await, uwp

Estoy implementando una app en UWP.Y tengo un método que llama a otro método.Y lo que me pasa es que el método continua sin haber esperado a que el usuario seleccione una opción del contentdialog.¿Cómo hago para que espere la respuesta del usuario del contentdialog?

```
var task =await DisplayMatriculaRemolqueDialog(tipoCodigoBarras.MatriculaRemolque);
if (task){ ...}

private async Task<bool> DisplayMatriculaRemolqueDialog(string matriculaRemolque)
    {
        try
        {
            bool resultado = false;
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                ContentDialog noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog()
                {
                    Title = "Pistola",
                    Content = "Matrícula remolque:" + matriculaRemolque + "\n ¿ Desea continuar?",
                    PrimaryButtonText = "Sí",
                    SecondaryButtonText = "No"

                };
                ContentDialogResult result = await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
                continuar = result == ContentDialogResult.Primary;
                resultado = continuar;
            });
            return resultado;

                                                                                          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                m_errorIdentificador = true;

                this.InfoCodBarras.Text = "Código de barras leído: " + matriculaRemolque;
                this.Resultado.Text = "Operacion realizada.";
            });
            return false;
        }                        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya he visto la solución en este link
https://www.pedrolamas.com/2016/01/20/awaiting-the-coredispatcher/
El último ejemplo de código es el que explica el caso usando la clase TaskCompletionSource